# Strange issue with android volume

Tags: java, android, volume

I have created an android application , which works just fine .
in the application i am using media player to play .wav files , which also is working fine.

the only problem comes , when i try to increase the volume of the application ,
just when i touch the up-volume button , the volume for call increases
but the volume for application remains same

any suggestion , what can be the effecting factor ??

here is my code to play audio

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;//as global var in activity
mediaPlayer=new MediaPlayer(); // inside onCreate() method
```

whenever i need to play audio i call this method

```
private void playAudio() {
        Log.d("hussi","before the media ");
        try {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            Log.d("hussi","so the file name passed is"+gif_char+".wav");
            AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = getApplicationContext().getAssets().openFd(gif_char+".wav");
            long start = descriptor.getStartOffset();
            long end = descriptor.getLength();
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(), start, end);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.start(); 

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Log.d("hussi","1===>>>"+e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("hussi",e.getMessage());
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            Log.d("hussi","2===>>>"+e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.d("hussi","3===>>>"+e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("hussi","4===>>>"+e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("hussi","5===>>>"+e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: <code> setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC); </code>in your onCreate() method. That tells the OS that the volume buttons should affect the "media" volume when your application is visible, and that's the volume it uses for your application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);`  
in your onCreate() method. That tells the OS that the volume buttons should affect the "media" volume when your application is visible, and that's the volume it uses for your application.
Remember your application needs focus.